# Quantified-self devices to measure tilt

Tags: poker-tools, psychology

Are there any good gadgets for measuring tilt and emotional stress at the moment on the market?

I was thinking that the quantified-self makers Jawbone and their newest device Up3 would be a contender, or at least with some 3rd party software. But so far I haven't read anything about it.

The only thing I can come up with is Dave Asprey and his Emwave to measure heart rate variablility. That device seems like a hot contender but has got some critique for being psuedo-science.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use youtube search with "concentration camp" and "ww 2" - I think that should untilt you really quick. Or some NASA documentary on youtube - that will show you how not so important is this poker thing at all ;)

Comment: The problem with things like heart rate is that tilt doesn't necessarily correspond to physiological phenomena.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend doing some mindfulness exercises. Recognising your own tilt is really useful and allows you to deal with it.

Being aware of your current state of mind will give you a clear advantage in poker and in life in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find your heart rate and think there is a correlation there, you can always just learn how to feel your own pulse; it's really easy.
However, I would say the best device for recognizing tilt is your own brain.
You should be paying very careful attention to your emotional state after every big loss/win or tough decision and in all of these cases, especially if you don't have a good grip on your self-awareness tightening up your game for a few hands. If you take some time working on it while you are playing, you will be able to tell when your tilted without any gadgets at all!